# How can I give Interface a boolean variable?

Tags: java, android, interface

My interface is this

```
public interface AndroidStuff {

    public void adShower();
    public void shareActivity();
}
```

I need to give it a `boolean watched` and not initialize it, then modify that boolean in my main Android class where I implement this Interface, so I can check if it is false or true from my non Android class(I'm using LibGdx).

this is the `AndroidApplication` class:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AndroidStuff {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MyGdxGame(this), config);
        HeyzapAds.start("1",this);
        IncentivizedAd.fetch();
    }

    @Override
    public void adShower() {
        IncentivizedAd.display(this);
        IncentivizedAd.fetch();
        IncentivizedAd.setOnIncentiveResultListener(new HeyzapAds.OnIncentiveResultListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String tag) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onIncomplete(String tag) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void shareActivity() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

I need to check from non Android class if the `onComplete` has been called.

Comment: all the interface variables are public static and final. so you can't change them. what you need is an abstract class

Comment: But I can't implement an abstract class?

Comment: You can extend an abstract class instead.

Comment: yes, you can't implement that class and you must have to extend that one. You need something 'trait' like behavioural abstraction. but unfortunately that does not exists in Java.

Comment: Im allready extending the AndroidApplication class , but all I need is to check if an ad video is watched, I'll update the question.

Comment: @TheProphet specify why do you need and update the question then someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put instance variables in interfaces in Java, but what you CAN do is:

```
public interface AndroidStuff
{
    boolean getWatched();
    // Your other methods...
}
```

and then in your class that implements that interface:

```
public class ExampleClass implements AndroidStuff
{
    private boolean watched;
    @Override
    public boolean getWatched()
    {
        return watched; // Or whatever logic you like
    }
    // The rest of the class...
}
```

That's what you might to do if you want to use an interface. Otherwise just make `AndroidStuff` an `abstract class`.

Comment: But also note that Java doesn't allow multiple inheritance, so if you make `AndroidStuff` an `abstract class` your child subclasses won't be able to inherit anything else.

Comment: the getWatched(); did the trick, I had done the same thing , but I forgot I had to return the watched

Answer (score 1):

After update, what about the simple static field which will be updated in onComplete()?

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AndroidStuff {

 public static boolean isWatched;

 // on onComplete() set true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the interface variables must be public static and final. so you can't change them. what you need is an `abstract class`.

**Edit:**
In your case; you need a callback from onComplete inside your application class to somewhere else.

There are two possible solutions:
1. you can use static flag variable like this

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AndroidStuff{
  public static boolean isAdShown = false;

....onComplete(){
  isAdShown  = true; 
  }
}
```

then check it inside otherclass  like this

```
if(AndroidLauncher.isAdShown) ....
```

2. Define an interface inside your application class that gives you callback:

   ```
       public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AndroidStuff{
     private CallBack callback;
     public void registerCallBack(Callback callback){
           this.callback = callback;
     }
     public interface CallBack{
           void onAdShown();
     }

   }
   ```

Now; let your other class register callback and provide implementation for that callback;

```
    public OtherClass implements AndroidLauncher.CallBack{
    public OtherClass(){
     instanceOfApplicationClass.registerCallback(this);
    }

     @Override
     public void onAdShown(){
       //here you get the callback when ad is shown
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface AndroidStuff {

   public void adShower();
   public void shareActivity(boolean isChecked);
}
```

then when you implement it in activity you will get this variable for use

```
 public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AndroidStuff {



 @Override
 protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
  initialize(new MyGdxGame(this), config);
  HeyzapAds.start("1",this);
  IncentivizedAd.fetch();
  }

  @Override
  public void adShower() {
  IncentivizedAd.display(this);
  IncentivizedAd.fetch();
  IncentivizedAd.setOnIncentiveResultListener(new HeyzapAds.OnIncentiveResultListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String tag) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onIncomplete(String tag) {

    }
    });
    }

   @Override
   public void shareActivity(boolean isChecked) {
   //here youwill get boolean variable for use
   } 



 @Override
 protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
 super.attachBaseContext(base);
 MultiDex.install(this);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 }
 }
```